# Whats the proper way to add Github library to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I'm trying to add library in Android Studio Project, but I am getting an error:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

All I have done is followed tutorials and guides from Stack Overflow

1. First added the library to root of my project.

[image]

2. then went to my settings.gradle and done that

   ```
   include ':app'
   include ':ImagePicker'
   project(':ImagePicker').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../ImagePicker/library')
   ```
3. then went to my dependencies and in app.gradle

   ```
   compile project(':ImagePicker')
   ```

but still getting particular stated error.

[Library Link](https://github.com/Mariovc/ImagePicker)

Comment: possible but it isnt :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a much better way to add this library to your project:

> Add this permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```
>
> Add it in your *root* `build.gradle` at the end of repositories:
>
> ```
> allprojects {
>   repositories {
>     // Add this line
>     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Add `ImagePicker` dependency to your *app*'s `build.gradle` file:
>
> ```
> dependencies{
>     compile 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.2.0'
> }
> ```

In that case you don't need to add the source code to your libray. This should also speedup your app compile time since the library doesn't need to be compiled again and again. So you will use the library as a normal dependency.

Comment: both of them didnot work still getting the same error

Comment: also tried cleaning but with no luck

Comment: updated the answer with link at bottom

Comment: Did you see this section? https://github.com/Mariovc/ImagePicker#add-it-to-your-project

Comment: yes I saw it but as i do so I am unable to get updated code with a fix merged a few hours back in 1.2.0 . I was using a version below 1.0.5 and updated to newer version but still the library loaded didn't contain merged code

Comment: Okay that is a reason. My first revision of my answer should work. However i need to go now I'll validate my answer later and will add a section how I made it work. Keep in mind that this may take some hours. Sorry.